# Manhwa where the main character is a rich businessman who dies and gets isekaied to a medieval fantasy world

Tags: story-identification, manga, money

I remember him making a delivery service after getting reborn; he also made an insurance company. It all takes place in a medieval fantasy world. He also found a witch in a coffin being trapped in a ring who later saved his life. Does anyone know what manhwa this is?

Comment: When did you read this?: Was it on a website? Black and white? Color? Do you know what hair color the protagonist or the witch had? Can he see his own stats or those of others?

Comment: Yes in color, im sure he cant see others stats, yes i read it on a website, i think the mc had gray snd the witch black hair

Answer (score 2):

I think it's *[Rules for Peddling in Another World](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/rules-for-peddling-in-another-world)*.

> If you accidentally crossed over into another world, what kinds of abilities would you need to reach your peak in life? Would you became an Enchanter? A Hero? Or maybe a Cultivator of Immortal Techniques? Of course not. You would take advantage of your present day knowledge in this other world to do business and earn big bucks!
>
> [image: Front cover of Rules for Peddling in Another World]

[image: The girl in the coffin in Chapter 3] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

[image: Plans to make a delivery company in Chapter 8] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

[image: Plans to sell insurance in Chapter 25] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you please describe this manhwa and explain how it matches the question?