# Manga in which the main character is transported to another world and decides to sell insurance, before meeting the demon lord

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

Looking for a manga I read a few years ago.

The main character gets transported to another world and decides to sell insurance. He then meets the demon lord, who was also transported into the same world. I say transported, but I can’t remember if it was transportation or reincarnation.

I cannot remember if it was Japanese or Korean style, I think it was Japanese.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall the names of any characters or locations?

Comment: Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: I assume the demon lord runs the insurance company?

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se] SE! Please consider [registering](/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/162827) to more features of the site. As an unregistered user, you can’t vote, and you’ll lose access to your account if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Once you lose access, you won’t be able to accept answers or edit posts (without requiring other users’ approval) that you made under the unregistered account. Registering an account is easy, and it will allow you to participate more fully in our community.

Answer (score 1):

As per the unaccepted answer to [Manhwa where the main character is a rich businessman who dies and gets isekaied to a medieval fantasy world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/270011/23243), could this be *[Rules for Peddling in Another World](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/rules-for-peddling-in-another-world)*?

> If you accidentally crossed over into another world, what kinds of abilities would you need to reach your peak in life? Would you became an Enchanter? A Hero? Or maybe a Cultivator of Immortal Techniques? Of course not. You would take advantage of your present day knowledge in this other world to do business and earn big bucks!

[image: Plans to sell insurance in Chapter 25] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

The protagonist, a successful businessman on Earth before he died choking on a jelly cup, waking up in a fantasy world as "Slime", the son of a destitute peasant who has just been hung for treason. He expects to follow the usual *isekai* setup of having an immensely useful gift, but his evaluation (meant to detect his hidden abilities as a spy so that they can execute him as well) shows that he has absolutely no magical, chi, or other talent. Out of pity for his sudden loss, and his seeming madness, his village bands together to provide him a hundred gold and an ostrich mount with which he can leave and seek his fortune. His initial business involves creating a delivery service, which then starts delivering food, before he gets waylaid by the nobles' merchant association, who arranges for an accident that leads to him being sentenced to death, only saved because of a necromancer who finds him amusing. She also lets him know that he is not the only person from another world, and the image shown looks like a demon king. He is introduced as a character in Chapter 51 as a mighty necromancer, and later meets with the protagonist and they swap stories.

[image: Princess Butterfly explaining the other person from another world] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

[image: The Necromancer King is tipped off by the name of "iVine"] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>